# Вылезает ошибка после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Почему-то выдает ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C://pythonProject/qrgenerator.py", line 18, in QR_generator
    qr = pyqrcode.create(value)
  File "C:\\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pyqrcode\__init__.py", line 111, in create
    return QRCode(content, error, version, mode, encoding)
  File "C:\\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pyqrcode\__init__.py", line 137, in __init__
    guessed_content_type, encoding = self._detect_content_type(content, encoding)
  File "C:\\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pyqrcode\__init__.py", line 307, in _detect_content_type
    c = content.encode('shiftjis')
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

```
import pyqrcode
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title('QR Генератор')
root.geometry('300x200+700+400')
root["bg"] = "#c0c0c0"

value = StringVar()

ent = Entry(textvariable=value, font='17')
ent.pack()
ent.place(x=55,y=5)


def QR_generator():
    qr = pyqrcode.create(value)
    qr.png('qrcode.png')



butt = Button(root, text='Генерировать', font='35', bg='#ccc', width=19, command=QR_generator)
butt.pack()
butt.place(x=55, y=33)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вы хотите сгенерировать изображение QR-кода ?

Answer (score 0):

У вас `value` - это объект класса `StringVar`, специфичного для tkinter. Очевидно, pyqrcode ничего не знает об этом классе.

По ошибке похоже (мне лень было смотреть документацию), что `pyqrcode.create()` ожидает, что ему передадут просто строку (у строки есть метод `encode`, в отличие от `StringVar`), поэтому нужно передавать не сам объект `value`, а строку из него:

```
def QR_generator():
    qr = pyqrcode.create(value.get())  # Метод get получает значение из объекта StringVar
    qr.png('qrcode.png')
```